# Contradiction in Convolution Solution

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering

[image: Question]
In this question, I solved the convolution for triangular pulse and the solution was
[image: Solution]
Now take k = 1, m = 1 , And as R = Ku/P0, R =
[image: R value]
So, for t<td u(t) is a function of t and for t>td its a constant (putting t = td)?
But when you do put the values in the equation of motion, F for t>td also comes to be constant. which is contradictory.

Comment: The expression inside the `integrate` function used to denote the triangular pulse viz, $p\cdot(1-\tau/t_d)$ is *not* correct for values of $t>t_d$ and $t<0$. It should probably be $p\cdot(1-\tau/t_d)\cdot (u(t)-u(t-t_d))$.

Comment: I did not get what u(t) is.
Can I use the singularity function? I don't know the syntax for it in Maxima or Matlab.

Comment: $p\cdot(1-\tau/t_d)$ does not ensure that the signal value is zero when $t>t_d$ and $t<0$. It might need to be modified before being sent to integration. $u(t)$ in my comment is the unit step function [here1](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/docs/manual/maxima_48.html#index-hstep) and [here2](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/docs/manual/maxima_338.html#unit_005fstep). I am not sure though.